# Compilation error when creating SFINAE based constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, class-template

During the implementation of a class that has SFINAE based ctor, I get the next error:
In template: no type named 'type' in 'std::enable_if<false, void *>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration

The SFINAE is based on previous template which is been worked on before.

The code  is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace infra {
namespace io {
struct IoDataFrameFactory {};
struct IoDataFrame {};
}


}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class IoDataFramePair : public infra::io::IoDataFrame {
 public:
  IoDataFramePair(std::istream &is, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &factory,
                  typename std::enable_if_t<(std::is_constructible_v<T1, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &> &&
                      std::is_constructible_v<T2, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &>), void *> = nullptr)
      : first(is, factory), second(is, factory)
  {
      checkSuffix(is);
  }
  
  IoDataFramePair(std::istream &is, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &factory,
                  typename std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_constructible_v<T1, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &>
                      &&
                          std::is_constructible_v<T2, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &>), void *> = nullptr)
      : first(is), second(is, factory)
  {
      checkSuffix(is);
  }
  
  IoDataFramePair(std::istream &is, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &factory,
                  typename std::enable_if_t<(std::is_constructible_v<T1, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &> &&
                      !std::is_constructible_v<T2, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &>), void *> = nullptr)
      : first(is, factory), second(is)
  {
      checkSuffix(is);
  }
  
  IoDataFramePair(std::istream &is, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &factory,
                  typename std::enable_if_t<(!std::is_constructible_v<T1, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &>
                      &&
                          !std::is_constructible_v<T2, std::istream &, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory &>), void *> = nullptr)
      : first(is), second(is)
  {
      checkSuffix(is);
  }
 
 private:
  int m_version;
  // Define other members and functions as needed
  
  void checkSuffix(std::istream &is)
  {
      // Implement checkSuffix logic
  }
  
  std::istream m_beginIS;
  std::istream m_middleIs;
  T1 first;
  T2 second;
};

int main()
{
    // Usage example
    std::stringstream is();  // You need to provide an actual input stream
    infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory factory;  // You need to provide an actual IoDataFrameFactory
    
    IoDataFramePair<int, double> pair1(is, factory);  // Calls the appropriate constructor
    IoDataFramePair<int, int> pair2(is, factory);     // Calls the appropriate constructor
    // Similar usage for other cases
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the types you test dependent types. Here are two ways adding `U1` and `U2` that defaults to `T1` and `T2`.

1. Not adding an argument to the function:

```cpp
template <class U1 = T1, class U2 = T2, std::enable_if_t<
        (std::is_constructible_v<U1, std::istream&,
                                    const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory&> &&
            std::is_constructible_v<U2, std::istream&,
                                    const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory&>)>* =
        nullptr>
IoDataFramePair(std::istream& is, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory& factory)
    : first(is, factory), second(is, factory) {
    checkSuffix(is);
}
```

2. Still adding an argument to the function:

```cpp
template<class U1 = T1, class U2 = T2>
IoDataFramePair(
    std::istream& is, const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory& factory,
    std::enable_if_t<
        (!std::is_constructible_v<U1, std::istream&,
                                    const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory&> &&
            std::is_constructible_v<U2, std::istream&,
                                    const infra::io::IoDataFrameFactory&>)>* =
        nullptr)
    : first(is), second(is, factory) {
    checkSuffix(is);
}
```

... and do the same for the other two constructors.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/s8PTG6o7Y) - Note:
I prefer to keep the extra argument out of the constructors (version 1 above) so I used that approach in all constructors in the demo.

---

Note: You have other problems, like trying to default construct `istream`s and trying to initialize and `int` and a `double` with an `istream`, but I think that's beside the point.